# How to controll windowed watchdog (WWDG) with dynamically scaling CPU frequencies?

Tags: arm, watchdog

I have a project using ARM Cortex M4 with scaling CPU frequencies dependent on the workload. I would like to use the WWDG because it allows a lot more options like interrupt on watchdog. Question is: is there any standard workaround for variable time length CPU tick?

Comment: does the watchdog need to run on the CPU clock?  Does the system/rtos tick need to run on the CPU clock?   If not, then the CPU scaling frequencies doesn't matter.

Comment: As an aside, if you can't vary the regulator voltage based on the CPU frequency, there's no real value in varying the frequency based on the workload.  Just put the processor to sleep with the WFI instruction.   The ARM does a good job at clock gating when inactive, so you're just adding complexity and not really changing the number of clock transitions per unit of work (So you're not really affecting the power per unit work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very different solutions for that. Which to choose depends on your setting and your aaplication (more precise on its criticality). If the WD is used only to detect a stuck in an uncritical application, i.e., no serious danger of hurts to human, animals, or expensive material damage, then a normal WD with relaxed timing is absolutely sufficient. If the aplication is critical and you expect some serious misbehaviour in case of underrunning a lower time limit, then a WWDG can be used.

So I have two possible solutions in mind, one simple and one complex; which one is best for your use case depends on what you require for your system (I cannot judge as you didnt tell on what kind of system you are working). The first solution would be to configure the WWD in a way that the limits are fullfilled with any of the settings. So the configuration is quite relaxed but sufficient for many use cases. So you dont have to take care for the dynamic switching of clock frequencies.

The more complex solution is to measure the time between to clock changes and determine the target time till the next WD serve with the newly selected frequency. When no more change happens in between, then the WD will beserved at that time. Otherwise you take the intervall with the latest frequency in account and calculate the next relative time stamp when the WD has to be served. But it depends on the timing you require if this is can be realized or not. If your timing is very tough (e.g, <1ms), then this would not realy be a viable option. But on the other hand, if the calculation is complex, you will obtain a simple challange response WD that checks the health your ALU in addition to the timing.